QuantConnect LEAN signal count in backtesting
I have a trading strategy which I want to implement in the Quant Connect LEAN platform. I have a specific execution criterion. If open price=close price for any instrument on a daily timeframe, my strategy executes orders on the next candle (next day/session). Whether it places buy or sell, that is totally different logic, and I am not interested in that. My problem is, I want LEAN back testing program to identify the specific candles on which open price is equal to close price and then compile those events into a text file (instrument name, date/time of the signal, price). I have tried to implement this into LEAN:
class MyAlgorithm(QCAlgorithm):
    def Initialize(self):
        self.spy = self.AddEquity("IDEA", Resolution.Daily)
        self.history = self.History(self.spy, 100, Resolution.Daily)


    for time, bar in data.Bars.items():
        if bar.Open == bar.Close:
            self.Debug(f"Candle at {time} has Open == Close: {bar}")

Now, the core issue is, how do you run this screener (indicator, whatever) on 1500 instruments at the same time? Manually, it's tedious. The parameter optimization feature only allows to configure the parameters in the algorithm and run it on a single instrument. Correct me if I'm wrong. My objective= same parameters, multiple instruments, bulk historical data (20 years). Please share insights on this.

If you ever post working code, here are some other suggestions to further improve your question.  Since you are new to this site, you should add a specific language tag to the question.  Always define terms like QuantConnect and LEAN; it is better to assume people don't know what you mean.  You can edit links into the question for this.

Thank you for reviewing my question. I have implemented the changes.

Welcome to the Code Review Community. We only review code that is working as expected, there are other sites that will answer How to questions. We will be happy to review the code in order to help you improve your coding skills once the code is implemented the way you want. Please read Where can I get help? and How do I ask a good question?.
